# How to stop stepping into .NET source code using TestDriven.NET?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging, testdriven.net

I just started using TestDriven.NET to debug on my tests, here is my setup

TestDriven.NET 2.17 
VS 2008 SP1 
Windows XP

The problem I run into is on exception it keeps stepping into the .NET Framework source code.  I checked Tools > Options > Debugging and "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" is not checked and "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" is checked.

I right click on the test case and run debug with TD.NET.

So, how do I turn this off, so on exception it doesn't go into .NET Framework source?

Thanks,
Ray.

Comment: Which command are you using to run TD.NET?

Comment: I right click on the test case and run debug with TD.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blow away your .NET Framework symbols and change your symbol path to something weird, so the debugger can't step through it

Comment: I got it, I went to Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols and delete the Cache symbols from symbol servers to this directory.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you step in only when exception happens the solution is simpler:
Go to Debug -> Exceptions and uncheck all the checkboxes.